# Removing &NBSP; in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to remove all `&nbsp;`'s in my model with the following method :

```
def about_us_sans_spaces
  self.about_us = replace(self.about_us, "&nbsp;", " ")
end
```

Except! it turns out 'replace' isn't a method in rails. How would you remove the `&nbsp;`'s?

Mind you, I have already tried sanitized, simple_format. My view looks like this right now:

```
= truncate(sanitize(simple_format(organization.about_us_sans_spaces), :tags => ''), 125).titleize
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
def about_us_sans_spaces
  self.about_us.gsub!("&nbsp;", "")
end
```

Edit: Note that gsub() also accepts regex, so you can catch all instances regardless of capitalization like so:

```
about_us.gsub(/&nbsp;/i,"")
```

Comment: That's fantastic! Totally worked. Not entirely sure what you mean by '/&nbsp;/i,""  would that do the same thing as the previous example?

Comment: It would also replace instances of '&NBSP;' etc.

Comment: No, they do different things.

gsub("&nbsp;", "") will replace the literal "&nbsp;" with "", while gsub(/&nbsp;/i, "") will replace "&nbsp;", "&NbSp;", "&nbSP;" or any other possible capitalization combination. /&nbsp;/ matches "&nbsp;", the "i" flag makes it case insensitive.

http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Regexp.html